# latitude and longitude in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I want to get the nearest lan & lat of user's position and return with some other data, so I used the code below, but the resault is "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", why?!!

```
$branches = DB::table('stores')
     ->join('store_branches', 'stores.id', '=', 'store_branches.store_id')
     ->join('stores_categories','stores.category_id', '=', 'stores_categories.id')
     ->select('store_branches.name_en AS branch_name_en', 'stores.logo', 'stores.name_en', 'stores_categories.name_en AS category_name_en', 'store_branches.( 6367 * acos( cos( radians( ? ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( ? ) ) + sin( radians( ? ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance', [$data['lat'], $data['lng'], $data['lat']])
     ->groupBy('store_branches.name_en', 'stores.logo', 'stores.name_en', 'stores_categories.name_en')
     ->having('distance', '<', 30)
     ->orderBy('distance')
     ->get();

  return $branches;
```

Comment: seems the issue wasn't from this code, pls share more details, eg: the method's code

Comment: "message": "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
this is from postman

the method is post with 'lat' is 30 and 'lng' is 25

Comment: Please provide create table structures fore each models, sample data and expected result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you're trying to send Array param, which should be a String. I suspect the issue is somewhere in you API implementation, not in this piece of code. Try to debug and share more info if you find the right part of the code which causes the issue

Comment: in `select` function, you pass in `[$data['lat'], $data['lng'], $data['lat']]`. that's invalid tho, they must separate by ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I used selectRaw instead of select change the syntax and it worked
Thanks all.